# Gérondif et incise, quelle proposition est référencée ?

Tags: incises, gérondif

Il y a actuellement dans ma ville une campagne de sensibilisation dont une des affiches est la suivante :

[image: Tu crois vraiment qu’en m’insultant je vais te donner mon 06 ?]

> Tu crois vraiment qu’en m’insultant je vais te donner mon 06 ?

---

Personnellement, j’interprête la phrase comme suit :

> Si tu m’insultes, tu crois vraiment que je vais te donner mon numéro ?

à savoir que l’incise se réfère à la première proposition et qu’il s’agit donc du « tu » qui est en train d’insulter.

Ma compagne, elle, pense que l’incise se rapporte à la seconde proposition et qu’il faudrait comprendre la phrase comme suit :

> Pendant que je m’insulte, je vais te donner mon numéro ; tu le crois vraiment ?

ce qui (et je le concède) est une contruction assez bizarre et, à moins que la personne qui parle soit atteinte du syndrome de la Tourette, assez peu probable. Une tournure plus correcte serait l’une des suivantes :

> Tu crois vraiment qu’en m’insultant tu auras mon 06 ?
>
> Tu crois vraiment que si tu m’insultes je vais te donner mon 06 ?

Elle me soutient que, dans ce genre de cas, l’incise se rapporte forcément avec la seconde proposition et en tire donc son sujet ; pour moi, étant placée entre les deux propositions, elle peut venir soutenir l’une ou l’autre, les deux sens étant possible, le contexte aidant à choisir une interprétation plutôt qu’une autre.

Quelques exemples supplémentaires sur le même modèle et nos interprétations :

> Tu penses vraiment qu’en écrivant ça au tableau je vais mieux comprendre ?
>
> *Moi* : Tu écris au tableau et je comprends mieux.
>
> *Elle* : J’écris au tableau et je comprends mieux.

> Tu crois qu’en dormant je suis plus beau ?
>
> *Tous les deux* : Je dors et je suis beau.

Ceci étant, en cherchant ces constructions similaires, j’ai voulu dire :

> Je suis convaincu qu’en criant très fort tu vas avoir mal aux oreilles

qui m’a parru mal construite (sans savoir expliquer pourquoi) si je voulais dire que si « je » crie très fort, « tu » vas avoir mal aux oreilles. Ce que je voulais dire étant :

> Je suis convaincu qu’en criant très fort je vais te faire avoir mal aux oreilles.

---

Quelles sont donc les règles qui s’appliquent dans ce genre de cas ? N’y a-t-il qu’une seule interprétation possible ou bien est-ce que les deux sont valables jusqu’à ce que le contexte vienne favoriser une interprétation plutôt qu’une autre ?

Pourquoi mon dernier exemple sonne-t-il faux dans le contexte que je voulais lui donner mais pas la phrase de l’affiche ?

Comment: Bonjour ! C'est quoi le « 06 » ?

Comment: @un3hiv3r: cela ferait une nouvelle question intéressante ! En France (et uniquement en France), il s'agit d'un terme familier pour désigner le numéro de téléphone portable. Cette dénomination vient du préfixe "06", par lequel commencent les numéros de portable dans le système de numérotation téléphonique française.

Comment: Les nouveaux numéros attribués sont maintenant en "07", mais l'expression perdure.

Comment: J'ai dû beaucoup tordre ma réflexion pour comprendre de la même façon que ta copine a compris, mais son interprétation est grammaticalement correcte (tout comme la tienne). Cependant je pense qu'absolument personne en France ne va comprendre cette phrase dans ce sens, ou ne va se dire qu'elle est mal formulée et qu'elle prête à confusion.

Comment: @Destal oui, mais ma compagne est d'origine Polonaise, d'où son interprétation basée sur des règles d'usage (comme suggéré par LPH) plutôt que de bon sens (comme suggéré par jlliagre).

Comment: @Greg Merci pour l'explication. Un truc qui me trouble un peu dans la pub c'est que je peux faire une lecture à l'effet que si je suis gentil alors on devrait me donner son 06. Il s'agirait d'un non sequitur.

Comment: @409_Conflict Ah, j'apprends le polonais donc j'imagine bien sa façon de voir le gérondif. Il est clair que l'usage qu'on en fait peut être contre-intuitif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En se référant à « *Le Bon Usage* » on peut conclure que la formulation n'est pas idéale.

> Pour la clarté de la phrase, le participe en tant qu'épithète détachée et le
>   gérondif, qui est toujours détaché du nom (ou du pronom) support, *doivent se construire de telle sorte que leur rapport avec le nom (ou le pronom)
>   ne prête à aucune équivoque*. Il est souhaitable, notamment, que le participe ou le gérondif détachés, surtout en tête d'une phrase ou d'une proposition, aient comme support le sujet de cette phrase et de cette proposition :
>
> - ACCOUDÉ à un coin des remparts de la forteresse où s'accrochait sur le vide quelque touffe de fleurs sèches, je cernais d'un seul coup d'œil son étendue menacée (GRACQ, Rivage des Syrtes, p. 2 8 ) .
> - En SE PLAIGNANT, on se console (MUSSET, Poés. nouv., Nuit d'oct.).
>
> (italiques de user **LPH**)

Il n'y aurait pas de règle prescrivant une construction précise mais une directive générale dictant que si une construction donnée semble douteuse il vaut mieux en changer pour une formulation dont on est sûr, ce qui est souvent quelque chose dont on dispose dans son arsenal syntaxique.

Par exemple la phrase suivante n'est pas souhaitable par ce que « budget » n'est pas le pêcheur.

- En pêchant un peu par jours de froid, son budget n'était plus une cause de souci pour lui. (user **LPH**)

> Tu crois vraiment qu’en m’insultant je vais te donner mon 06 ?

- Tu crois vraiment qu’en m’insultant *tu* vas avoir mon 06 ? (*« Je » disparait et le problème aussi.*)
- En m'insultant, tu crois vraiment que tu vas obtenir mon numéro ?
- C'est en m'insultant que tu crois vraiment avoir mon numéro ?

On  est en effet porté à croire que « en m'insultant » a « je » pour support ; cela découle  de l'habitude prise par la  vérification à la lecture de l'idéal reconnu  par le LBU  (il est souhaitable que le gérondif en tête de proposition ait comme support le sujet de cette proposition) et donc que l'interprétation en désaccord avec le contexte est celle qui s'impose ; la phrase est donc mal construite.

« En m’insultant » fait partie de la subordonnée, pas de la principal ; il ne peut rien y avoir entre une principale et une subordonnée si ce n'est le mot lien qui détermine la relation.

Il n'y a qu'une interprétation possible. « Je suis convaincu qu’en criant très fort tu vas avoir mal aux oreilles. » est incohérent si on veut dire que la personne représentée par « Je » fait l'action de crier ;  la phrase de l'affiche l'est aussi.

COMPLÉMENT EN RAISON DES DEMANDES SUPPLÉMENTAIRES D'EXPLICATION

On trouve ces questions formulées par user **409_Conflict** dans les commentaires mais elles sont répétées ci-dessous en italiques.

*Il est souhaitable, mais ce n'est pas une règle, donc. Ce qui fait que l'on comprend très bien que, puisque « son budget » ne peut pas pêcher, c'est donc « lui » qui pêche. Ce qui explique aussi pourquoi je n'ai pas de problèmes avec la phrase de l'affiche mais que j'en ai un avec la phrase que j'ai essayé de construire : le contexte (le bon sens, comme le propose @jlliagre) ne permet pas de trancher convenablement qui supporte le gérondif… 
Par contre : « Il ne peut rien y avoir entre une principale et une subordonnée si ce n'est le mot lien qui détermine la relation. » Est-il possible d'avoir un peu plus de sources là dessus ? Parce que, in fine, c'est le point qui fait débat entre nous.*

1/ On le comprend très bien, oui, mais après réflexion ; la meilleure phrase, celle que l'on s'accorde à appeler celle du meilleur *style*, ou encore celle du *bon auteur*, c'est celle qui ne demande pas cet effort de réflexion supplémentaire et qui livre immédiatement son contenu.

2/ « Pas de problème avec la phrase de l'affiche… » ; le contexte force une interprétation dans la phrase de l'affiche : l'idée de l'acte amical en contradiction avec l'acte inamical induit plus ou moins, mais plus ou moins seulement, une interprétation préférentielle ; vous dépendez donc du contexte. Dans le cas de votre construction personnelle vous vous trouvez confronté à un contexte où rien ne dirige l'interprétation parce l'un tout aussi bien que l'autre des protagonistes que la phrase introduit peut être l'auteur de l'acte de crier. Il s'ensuit que cette construction qui laisse le contexte prendre le dessus sur la syntaxe dans certains cas n'est plus valable dans ce dernier parce qu'il n'y a pas la convention que le support se trouve dans la subordonnée (votre point de vue, que je trouve en erreur) et que ce support doit (de préférence) être le sujet de cette subordonné ; votre structuration est donc absolument ambigüe sans possibilité de la récupérer. Tout au contraire, si on s'en tient à une norme simple il n'y a d'ambiguïté en aucun cas et la communication de l'information se fait sans aucune hésitation ; ce sont en fin de comptes de simples principes à suivre, qui laissent le sens complètement dépendant de la syntaxe et qui sont plus faciles à retenir et à appliquer.

3/ Cette question de structure de la phrase complexe qui est la votre, où forcément un troisième élément figure de telle sorte que l'on pourrait selon un principe encore immatériel, soit l'associer avec la principale, soit avec la subordonnée et même avec ni l'une ni l'autre possiblement, tout cela étant ainsi puisque vous ne le caractérisez qu'en disant qu'il est « entre » les propositions, est pour moi quelque chose d'inexistant ; je n'en ai jamais entendu parler. J'ai fait un peu de recherche sur le sujet de la construction de la phrase et je n'ai rien trouvé. Il me semble que ce n'est pas une réalité de la grammaire française. De même, l'idée qu'une partie de la principale pourrait être emboitée dans une subordonnée ne me semble pas avoir trouvé d'application dans la grammaire française. Prenons un exemple dans lequel on pourrait avoir tendance à raisonner comme vous le faites, faute de la conclusion catégorique d'un expert, qui nous manque et qui nous dirait « non ce n'est pas possible ».

- Ils savaient bien que, sans avoir fini tôt, les choses étant ce qu'elles sont, il n'y aurait aucun espoir.

découpage 1 : Ils savaient bien sans avoir fini tôt, les choses étant ce qu'elles sont […]. — (*alternative*) Sans avoir fini tôt, les choses étant ce qu'elles sont, ils savaient bien  |  qu'il n'y aurait aucun espoir. 
Selon cet arrangement « savoir » est conditionné par l'état des choses.

découpage 2 : Ils savaient bien sans avoir fini tôt | que, les choses étant ce qu'elles sont, il n'y aurait aucun espoir.
Selon ce découpage la possibilité d'un espoir est conditionnée par l'état des choses. On ne peut choisir quel verbe est modifié que par la place de la locution adverbiale.

découpage 3 *Les découpages précédents ne semblent pas possibles. Le seul possible est le découpage dans lequel les deux locutions adverbiales font partie de la subordonnée.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101794/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-gerondif-et-incise-quelle-proposition-est-reference).

Answer (score 3):

Il n'y a qu'une interprétation raisonnablement possible.

> En m'insultant, tu crois vraiment m'inciter à te donner mon numéro de portable ?

La formule d'une autre affiche de la même série est construite sur un modèle similaire mais l'absence de première personne écarte toute ambiguïté :

[image]

La « règle » qui permet de déterminer le sujet d'un gérondif français est le bon sens.

C'est lui qui permet de distinguer :

> Je suis convaincu qu’en criant très fort, tu m'entendras de chez toi.
>
> Je suis convaincu qu’en criant très fort, je t'entendrai de chez moi.

et ce, malgré la construction peu académique de la deuxième phrase dont le sujet du gérondif n'est que sous-entendu. La phrase signifiant :

> Je suis convaincu qu’en criant très fort, tu te feras entendre de chez moi.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Et pourquoi pas ? Dans le sens de « je (me) siffle pour me complimenter, c’est vraiment ce que tu crois ? » C’est ce genre d’interprétation « bizarre » dans le cadre du bon sens, mais supportée par Le Bon Usage comme l’indique la réponse de LPH qui a fait naître ce conflit d’interprétation avec ma compagne. Même si on est tous les deux d’accord que le sens voulu par la campagne étant bien, pour la phrase originelle, que « tu » siffles et « je » donne son numéro.

Comment: J'ai accepté la réponse de @LPH car je trouve qu'elle répond plus en détail aux questions que je me pose. Mais cette réponse m'est aussi utile pour la "règle" du bon sens. Y-a-t-il des sources à ce sujet ?

Answer (score 1):

« Stop au harcèlement de rue » tel est le message de l'affiche. Le soulignage emphatique renvoie également ce message, tout comme l'interprétation de la phrase.

La phrase est bien construite au niveau sémantique car le gérondif permet d'exprimer  plusieurs compléments circonstanciels en parallèle en suscitant d'abord l'interrogation de l'observateur (impression paradoxale).

En ce qui concerne vos autres questions, il s'agit d'erreurs de compréhension.

**Référence :** [article du Nouvel Observateur](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/le-gerondif-71.php).