# Que signifie un « 06 » ? / What does "06" mean?

Tags: sens

J'ai lu ceci :

> [...] je vais te donner mon 06.

Que signifie un « 06 » ?

---

I saw this:

> [...] je vais te donner mon 06.

What does "06" mean?

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/06#France

Comment: J'avais déjà [répondu](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40519/1109) indirectement à la question originale en proposant *En m'insultant, tu crois vraiment m'inciter à te donner mon numéro de **portable** ?* Il fallait bien sûr savoir que *portable* est le nom utilisé en France pour ce qu'on appelle un *gsm* en Belgique, un *Natel* en Suisse et un *cell* ou *cellulaire* au Canada.

Comment: Complémént pour la Belgique: un *portable* y désigne un ordinateur portable (ça m'a déjà valu un quiproquo très drôle lors d'une commande d'un "portable"..). Mais "numéro de portable" sera compris comme en France, comme il ne peut pas y avoir de numéro à un ordinateur portable.

Comment: Ouais la nébuleuse du portable, portatif, mobile, cellulaire, _smartphone_, je pense qu'on s'est déjà posé la question sur le site. Au Québec aussi parfois on hésite avec l'ordinateur. Le contexte aide souvent. En plus quand des gens se rencontrent en personne et qu'ils décident d'échanger leur numéro souvent on ne précise pas, souvent c'est ce qu'on a sous la main, le mobile.

Comment: "Complément pour la Belgique: un portable y désigne un ordinateur portable" En France aussi, cela peut aussi désigner un ordinateur portable, mais le sens le plus évident qui me vient à l'esprit, hors contexte spécifique, c'est le téléphone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[06](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/mon+06)  : numéro de téléphone portable (fam.)

[06](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/definition/06) : numéro de téléphone portable (nom masculin)

Ce nom vient du fait que pendant longtemps en France, tous les numéros de portable commençaient par « 06 ». Depuis 2010, on trouve également des numéros en « 07 ».

Ajoutons la référence suivante, qui est assez intéressante.

[réf.dico2rue](http://www.dico2rue.com/dictionnaire/mot/1476/06)
(68 yeah! 
21 bof)
[ 06 ]
Raccourci pour désigner le numéro de téléphone. Expression pseudo-branchée qui vous fera passer au mieux pour un être inintéressant, au pire pour le plus gros boulet de l'histoire de la fonderie, surtout dans un contexte de flirt.

" Et la demoizelle aux cheveux lisses, t'as pas un 06 ? Viens chez moi, que j'goûte aux délices de ton con qui plisse ! "

---

Addition suggérée par les commentaires de user **Laurent S**.

Ce terme court signifiant « numéro de téléphone portable » n'est apparemment pas utilisé au-delà des frontières de la métropole. Il n'est pas connu en Belgique et de toute évidence il ne l'est pas non plus au Canada. Cela se comprend vu que dans ces parties de la francophonie « 06 » ne correspond à rien dans le domaine de la téléphonie. Ce n'est donc pas  un terme idéal du point  de vue de la plus grande communauté des utilisateurs du français.

Comment: Simple curiosité digne d'un commentaire uniquement, est-ce qu'on dit un « 33 » pour un numéro de téléphone fixe ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas encore entendu celui-là une seule fois et la première fois que « 06 » m'est venu à l'esprit en tant que nouveau terme pour « numéro de téléphone » c'est lorsqu'il a été mentionné dans la question de laquelle vous le sortez vous-même. On peut voir que c'est très nouveau…

Comment: @un3hiv3r: je suppose que vous avez pensé au "33" pour un numéro de téléphone fixe comme c'est le préfixe international pour la France ? Comme il n'est pas nécessaire de composer ce préfixe pour un appel national (fixe ou mobile), les locuteurs français ne font pas référence à ce préfixe pour désigner les numéros de téléphonie fixe. On dira plutôt "numéro de téléphone fixe", ou familièrement "numéro fixe" (j'ai déjà entendu aussi "donne-moi ton fixe"). Ou dans un formulaire, on indiquera p.ex "téléphone (fixe)" ou "téléphone (domicile)"/téléphone (bureau)" selon le cas.

Comment: A noter comme l'a déjà commenté jlliagre sur la question que cette notion de "06 = numéro de téléphone portable" ne s'aplique qu'en France. Bien que certains connaissent l'expression en Belgique elle n'y fait aucun sens et n'y a pas d'équivalent.

Comment: @laurentS: j'ai déjà entendu en Belgique "donne-moi ton GSM" ou même "file-moi ton G" (bien qu'il y ait un petite ambiguité et que sans contexte, cela puisse aussi signifier qu'on demande le téléphone lui-même plutôt que le numéro).

Comment: Juste pour info, il existe des numéros de téléphone portable qui commencent par `07`,  le `06` arrivant à saturation.

Comment: @greg oui bien sûr, mais ces expressions ne sont pas vraiment typiques (si on excepte l'emploi du terme GSM). Dans le passé quand les téléphones portables n'existaient pas on aurait très bien pu dire "donne moi ton téléphone" pour avoir le numéro de quelqu'un, ceci j'imagine aussi bien en France qu'en Belgique

Comment: @Greg Merci ouais je connais _fixe_. Je pense que j'ai tendance à dire [_résidentiel_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=10465333), c'est peut-être un peu _vieux_.

Comment: @un3hiv3r pour un téléphone fixe, on n'utilise pas (ou alors très peu, mais je ne l'ai jamais entendu) l'abbréviation du `33`. Ce code n'est utilisé que pour joindre un téléphone français depuis un autre pays, ce code étant simplifié par le `0` en commnication interne (par exemple, `02 xx xx xx xx` est équivalent à `+33 2 xx xx xx xx`). De plus, la France est départagée en [5 zones](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_indicatifs_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9phoniques_en_France) pour ses téléphones fixes (le `2` dans mon exemple), ce qui n'empeche pas de "demander un 01 (ou 02 à 05)", mais très rare

Answer (score -3):

I think it means "aussi" like "also" or un another context  "cell number"

Comment: Maybe in a SMS-style writing but it would be `o6` (letter `o` and number `6` without pronouncing the final sound "s", so it sounds like `aussi`, similar to `b4` in English).

Comment: In context it couldn't be a short for "also" but I now see the connection.

Comment: 06 is pronounced (in standard French of France)"zero siss", with the "s", so it can't be a SMS abbreviation for "aussi".

Comment: Yeah it's right